# Add Conditions in the Controller to filter through records to pass the correct instance to the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This should be a small question. I have a students table and a classifieds table in my schema. The model/table relationship is hook up in a way that when I do

```
@student = Student.first.classifieds.all
```

in the rails console I will get all the classifieds ad for this particular student

```
[#<Classified id: 3, ad_content: "在BC附近BU也可以、需要女生一起租房子、看了几处、俩人去租非常合算、限女生", ad_title: "BU和BC旁边的房子求室友一起租 ", student_id: 16, created_at: "2013-09-17 19:20:43", updated_at: "2013-09-17 19:49:31", location: "Allston">, #<Classified id: 1, ad_content: "Malden Towers 宽敞客厅出租，附带阳台，窗外是公寓的花园，客厅可用窗帘或木板隔开， 每月4...", ad_title: "Malden Towers 客厅出租 400/月", student_id: 16, created_at: nil, updated_at: "2013-09-17 19:47:55", location: "Malden">]
```

I am trying to filter through the records with specific conditions so only the records that satisfy this specific condition can be passed to the view therefore appear on that particular page.

I want to display the record only if the location is equal to malden.

in my students_controller.rb I have this

```
def malden_index
  @student = Student.first 
  for classified in @student.classifieds.all
    return classified if classified['location'] == 'Malden'
  end
```

I have this in my view

```
<%= classified.ad_content %>
```

I am getting this error

```
undefined local variable or method `classified'
```

I have three  questions

1. can I add the conditions in my view ? or does it have to be in my controller?
2. are my records returned to me in array data type?
3. What is the problem in my code? (I think its pretty straight forward)(the classified should be each record, then return the record only if the location key is equal to malden)

Answer (score 1):

First off: in the view you can only reach instance variables defined in the controller. So the `for` loop does not gather anything that is reachable in the view.

So you could fix that by doing

```
def malden_index
  @student = Student.first
  @classifieds = @student.classifieds.where('location="Malden"')
end
```

and in your view iterate over all the `@classifieds`.

Now notice: this is completely hardcoded. 
I would solve this as follows: instead of using a separate `index` method, use the `show` action (of a student), check if a location is given, and if so, filter the classifieds accordingly.

That would look like this

```
def show
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  @classifieds = @student.classifieds
  if params[:location]
    @classifieds = @classifieds.where('location = ?', params[:location]
  end
```

end

and then you would build the url as follows `/students/1?location=malden`.

If you then add the following route to `config/routes.rb`

```
get '/students/:id/:location', to: 'students#show'
```

you could improve that to `/students/1/malden`.

Comment: I understand your code, so the student id can be found instead of hard coded. The student id can then be passed in through the route to find that student. I have this `get '/students/:id/?location=malden'` is `?location=malden` the hard coded way of passing in location as malden in the route? I am getting routing error if I do `/students/1/malden` I guess my next question is how to pass in location as a params in route? I also tried `'/students/:id/:location'`

Comment: I am making a craigslist app so I want all classifieds ads that belong to all students to be displayed on a certain category/page (location = malden, all the ads are housing) eventually organized by date. Would your approach be now too complicated due to the nature of my app?

Comment: So if you have an url like `/students/1?location=malden` malden is a parameter, it is not hardcoded. Change the url and the code keeps on working. The hardcoded way was without any parameter and always returning the first student and location malden.  I added the needed route to clean up the url, so you can write `/students/1/malden`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You shouldn't add this condition filtering in the view. It's much better when done in the controller.
2. The filtering can be done in multiple ways. It is usually best and fastest to let the database do the work:

   ```
   @student.classifieds.where(:location => 'Malden').all
   ```
3. You can either forward variables by making them an instance variable `@classifieds` or pass it as local variable to your view with `render 'malden_index', :locals => {:classifieds => @student.classifieds.all}`

In general, the approach with `return` in your for-loop doesn't result in your desired filter. Either use my suggestion from #2 or build your array like this

```
@classifieds = []
for classified in @student.classifieds.all
    @classifieds << classified if classified['location'] == 'Malden'
end
```

Or shorter and more 'ruby-way':

```
@classifieds = @student.classifieds.keep_if{|cf| cf['location'] == 'Malden'}
```

You could then access the @classifieds array in your view. Still, I very much suggest you rather use a database filter if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
def malden_index
  @student = Student.first 
  @classified = @student.classifieds.find_by_location("Malden")

end
```

In view:

```
<%= @classified.ad_content %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
def malden_index
  @student = Student.first 
  @classified =  @student.classifieds.where(location: 'Malden').first
end
```

in view:

```
<%= @classified.ad_content %>
```